# Are there conditions where $\pmb{ABA}^{-1}=\pmb B$ when $\pmb A$ and $\pmb B$ do not commute?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transpose

Given that $\pmb{AB} \ne\pmb{BA}$ and $\pmb{BA}^{-1} \ne\pmb A^{-1}\pmb B$, are there conditions where $\pmb{ABA}^{-1}=\pmb B$ ?

I am working in the context of a continuous, LTI system $\pmb{\dot x}(t)=\pmb{Ax}(t)+\pmb{Bu}(t)$ where the eigenvalues of $\pmb A$ have strictly negative real parts. I know that in at least one case $\pmb Ae^{\pmb At}\pmb A^{-1}=e^{\pmb At}$. An inverse question could be are there cases where $\pmb Ae^{\pmb At}\pmb A^{-1}\ne e^{\pmb At}$ ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Wait... If I understand correctly, I think $ABA^{-1}=B$ is equivalent to $AB=BA$...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.   If $ABA^{-1}=B$,  then right multiplying by A gets us
$$ABA^{-1}A=BA$$
$$ABI=BA$$
$$AB=BA$$

Similarly, if $A$ is invertible,  then you can start with $AB=BA$ and right multiply by $A^{-1}$ to reverse the steps.  So if $A$ is invertible, the two conditions are equivalent.